# jQuery/asp.net - Enable/Disable button only after user enters text in the textboxes and selects a value from the dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

**This is the aspx code for the controls** The feature that I want over here is that when I enter the value for the textboxes and select a dropdown value.. only after that should the button be enabled else the button should be disabled.

```
<div id="div1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Part Number:</label>
            <asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control" ID="itemOne" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control" ID="itemTwo" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Price:</label>
            <asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control" ID="itemThree" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Weight:</label>
            <asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control" ID="itemFour" runat="server" Style="width: 100px" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control" ID="miscItemQuantity" runat="server" Style="width: 80px" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownList" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="150" />
            <%-- Items are added dynamically from the codebehind --%>
        </div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="addItem" type="submit" Text="Add Item" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right"></asp:Button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code that I have tried to enable and disable the button with just one textbox

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=itemOne.ClientID%>").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
            $("#<%=addItem.ClientID%>").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=addItem.ClientID%>").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

> **I will be very glad to receive any solutions.**

Comment: use input event and check the text. also attack an event to the select to detect selection change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. First add a listener to each TextBox and DropDownList in `div1` to check for changes. Then validate all controls withing the div for the correct values and set the button visibility accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#div1 input[type='text']").keyup(function () {
            checkValues();
        });

        $("#div1 select").change(function () {
            checkValues();
        });

        checkValues()
    });

    function checkValues() {
        var isValid = true;

        $("#div1 input[type='text']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

        $("#div1 select").each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') === 0) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

        if (isValid) {
            $("#<%=addItem.ClientID%>").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=addItem.ClientID%>").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I made few changes to the solution you provided which works great. I will post my side of the solution after I am done with adding few more changes to it. Thanks again.