# Best way to loop through text box's in a div to see if the have data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have a div tag on a content page that has 10 text box's in it. They all start with txb and then a name, ex. txbSubmittedBy and txbOrderEntryDate. I want to loop through all the text box's to check that the user has entered data into them before processing the page.

What is the best way to accomplish this? For Each? I though about using a With statement but I am not sure if you can pattern match on the control name. I do not have any code because I haven't written any yet because i am not sure how to do this.

Here is the asp code for the div.

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="dataheader">
        <div class="row PadLeft">
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSubmittedBy" Text="Submitted By:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbSubmittedBy" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQarEntryDate" Text="QAR Entry Date:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                &ensp;<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbQarEntryDate" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
           </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblJobNumber" Text="Job #:"  CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbJobNumber" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row PadLeft">
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns PadLeft">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPoNumber" Text="PO #:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary"  />
                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbPoNumber" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOrderEntryDate" Text="Order Entry Date:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbOrderEntryDate" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                &emsp;&ensp;<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblShipDate" Text="Ship Date:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbShipDate" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row PadLeft">
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                &emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCustomerName" Text="Customer:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbCustomerName" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger customertxb" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text="Status" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbStatus" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSalesPerson" Text="Sales Person:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbSalesPerson" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row PadLeft">
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 headercolumns">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRplOrderNumber" Text="Rpl Order #:" CssClass="headerlbls text-primary" ToolTip="Check to Enter Replacement Order #" />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ckbRplOrderNumber" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="false" ToolTip="Check to Enter Replacement Order #" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbRplOrderNumber" CssClass="txbHeader text-danger" Visible="false" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using vb.net for the code behind so anything examples in vb would be great but I can convert to it if need be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to write the code. If you encounter an error while implementing it, then provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We aren't here to write your code for you, and we're not here to brainstorm the best way of doing something. We're here to solve specific programming problems.

Comment: See my answer here. The question is basically the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48307239/5836671

Comment: I would suggest you start by doing it one by one. Then, try looking at maybe using FindControl. But this is really business logic and should be in your business class.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. I was under the impression that this was a board where you could ask a question and NOT be bashed because you dont know something. Mason, exactly how do you write code for something that you dont understand AND cant find a correct answer for. Sometimes this site really blows sometimes... To all of you that did suggest something thanks... I will look else where for answer because the suggestions are not the direction I wanted to go.

Comment: @mbcharney I didn't downvote, and thought your question was ok. Appreciate you didn't necessarily like the suggestion in my answer but wondered what its shortcomings might be? It essentially does the same job as what you were suggesting with a loop, but using built-in tools. The end result would be very similar, if not identical, without you having to write any code on either client or server.

Comment: ADyson, my comment was for mason. I believe he is the one that down voted me. I may yet use your solution as I have not found a way that I was wanting to go.
Sorry any bad vibes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I want to loop through all the text box's to check that the user has
>   entered data into them before processing the page.".

Don't do this, it's not necessary.

Use the built-in ASP.NET validation controls instead. The `RequiredFieldValidator` sounds like it's relevant to your requirement. You can place them in your aspx page, one for each field you want to check, something like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="valSubmittedBy"
                    ControlToValidate="txbSubmittedBy"
                    Display="Static"
                    ErrorMessage="*"
                    runat="server"/>
```

I suggest you place each one next to the relevant field in the markup. They provide automatic client- and server-side validation of your fields.

You can also place a `ValidationSummary` control somewhere on your form, if you want to have a display of all the validation errors in one place, for ease of use.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think using RequiredFieldValidators could be teh way to go but this is possible. Sorry for the c# code:

```
foreach(var c in Page.Controls)
{
    if(c is TextBox)
    {
        var txt = c as TextBox;

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text)
        {
            //Your code here  
        }
    }
}
```

If the textboxes are in some other container control (such as a Panel) and not direct children of the page itself you should loop through the controls in that container instead.